# Laravel search form doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a search form and it searches base on ingredients (sort of tags) and not post titles.

When I search I will receive this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'food_vaght.ingredient_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `foods`.*, `food_vaght`.`ingredient_id` as `pivot_ingredient_id`, `food_vaght`.`food_id` as `pivot_food_id` from `foods` inner join `food_vaght` on `foods`.`id` = `food_vaght`.`food_id` where `food_vaght`.`ingredient_id` = 1) (View: C:\laragon\www\newproject\resources\views\front\search.blade.php)
```

This is my search form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/search" method="GET" role="search">
                          {{ csrf_field() }}
                          <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ingredients" class="hidden">Ingredient</label>
                                    <select class="tagsselector form-control" name="ingredients" multiple="multiple">
                                      @foreach($ingredients as $ingredient)
                                          <option value="{{ $ingredient->title }}">{{ $ingredient->title }}</option>
                                      @endforeach
                                    </select>
                          </div>

                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="mt-50 btn btn-custom">What to cook</button>
                                </div>

                       </form>
```

This is my `Search.blade.php` where results will return:

```
@extends('layouts.web')

@section('title', 'Search')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    searchbox
    <hr>

    <ol>
      @foreach($ingredients as $food)
        @foreach($food->foods as $res)
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#">{{$res->title}}</a></h4>
                <p class="card-text">{!!  str_limit($res->description, 10) !!}</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-block btn-link" href="#">Read More <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
      @endforeach
    </ol>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    random recipes
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Here is my `route`

```
Route::any('/search', 'FrontendController@search');
```

And this is my search function in `FrontendController`

```
public function search() {

      $searchTitle = request('title');

      $ingredients = null;

        $ingredients = Ingredient::when($searchTitle, function ($query) use ($searchTitle) {
            return $query->where('title', 'like', "%{$searchTitle}%");
          })
          ->paginate(10)
          ->appends(request()->query());

      return view('front.search', compact('ingredients'));
    }
```

Any idea on that? I didn't even call for `food_vaght` and `ingredient_id` but why they are in the error I don't understand.

**Update:**

Food_vaght migration:

```
public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('food_vaght', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('food_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('food_id')->references('id')->on('foods');
        $table->integer('vaght_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('vaght_id')->references('id')->on('vaghts');
      });
    }
```

`food_ingredient` migration:

```
public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('food_ingredient', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('food_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('food_id')->references('id')->on('foods');
        $table->integer('ingredient_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('ingredients');
      });
    }
```

`Foods` migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('foods', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->string('prepare')->nullable();
            $table->string('cook')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('foods', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('restrict')
                    ->onUpdate('restrict');
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

food model

```
  public function ingredients(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class);
  }
  public function vaghts(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Vaght::class);
  }
```

Vaght model:

```
  public function foods(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class);
  }
```

Ingredient model:

```
  public function foods(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'food_vaght');
  }
```

Comment: can you show us your `food_vaght` table

Comment: Can you also paste your database structure for tables `food_vaght ` and `foods` here? May be you are trying to get the column `ingredient_id ` from the wrong table.

Comment: @usrNotFound question updated.

Comment: @MayurPadshala updated

Comment: So `ingredient_id` is not in `food_vaght` table and you are trying to select the column that is not in the table. I think you want to look for `food_id`

Comment: @usrNotFound where did I try to get food_vaght? I'm not see that.

Comment: May be that's the problem in your model file.

Comment: @MayurPadshala idea?

Comment: @mafortis Please add your models too.

Comment: @MayurPadshala updated.

Comment: You have the Ingredient model:

```
public function foods(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'food_vaght');
}
```

But And that refers to `food_vaght`?

Comment: @MayurPadshala yes i already removed `, 'food_vaght'` from Ingredient model and it works now :) .   Thank you.

Comment: @mafortis glad to know that.

Comment: @MayurPadshala if you would like make it answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

The issue was in my ingredient model

```
public function foods(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'food_vaght');
  }
```

I changed it to:

```
public function foods(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class);
  }
```

Thanks to @MayurPadshala